# Почему htop и gnome-system-monitor по разному выводят количество ОЗУ?

Tags: linux, archlinux, gnome

htop показывает 2.70 gb а gnome-system-monitor 3.1 gb

[image: htop показывает 2.70 gb а gnome-system-monitor 3.1 gb]

Comment: Посмотрите в документацию каждой из програм. Если не поможет, то они с открытыми исходниками — в исходный код.

Comment: Почитайте - https://askubuntu.com/questions/787642/why-does-memory-usage-shown-in-system-monitor-differ-from-that-in-ps-mem